# Gvim doesn't remember cursor position within line if previous session ended on line 1

Tags: cursor-movement, gvim, microsoft-windows

I noticed that whenever I quit Gvim, it will remember the line and position within the line that the cursor was on, unless the cursor was on line 1.  If the cursor was on line 1, then it will not remember the position within line 1.

So if I have the cursor at the end of line 2 and I quit Gvim, then the next time I open the same file in Gvim, it will place the cursor at the end of line 2.

But if I have the cursor at the end of line 1 and I quit Gvim, then the next time I open the same file in Gvim, it will place the cursor at the *beginning* of line 1.

Is this a bug in Gvim?

I'm running Gvim 7.2 on Windows.

Comment: Are you using an autocmd to restore the cursor position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably use the `:autocmd` from `:help line()`:

```
:au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

Just drop the first branch of the conditional (`line("'\"") > 1 &&`).

Comment: Yes, that is located in the vimrc_example.vim file.

Comment: Note, there was a bug in loading buffers, that was just recently fixed.